# PineScript get today's current high and low price

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to obtain current high and low price, from the start of this trading day until now. I know I can get `high` and `low` price from `request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"D", high)` but that was from last daily candle. How should I get updated intraday high and low price?

For example, the price of AAPL started at $100 on 9:30, and it hits low at $90 on 10:00 and reaches high at $110 on 11:00, so now I should have to variables: `Current_High = 110` and `Current_Low = 90` when I am at 11:00. As time progresses in the day, the two prices keep updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're familiar with arrays, but I will explain them shortly:

Arrays are basically lists, that you can pass values in. I decided to pass values of type `float` inside it, because price values of type `series float`

You can...

- unshift values = insert them at the beginning of the array
- push values = insert them at the end of the array
- evaluate the maximum or the minimum
- many more things.. check out the [reference](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Arrays.html)

```
var highs = array.new_float()
var lows = array.new_float()

array.unshift(highs, high) // inserts high to the array
array.unshift(lows, low)   // inserts low to the array

if dayofweek != dayofweek[1] // if the day of current candle is not equal to the last candle day
    array.clear(highs)
    array.clear(lows)

current_high = array.max(highs) // maximum value of array highs
current_low = array.min(lows)   // minimum value of array lows

plot(current_high)
plot(current_low)
```

You could also just have one array (to save some calculation time maybe), but I think it's good to have two arrays for readability, and maybe to evaluate the highest low and the lowest high

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
indicator("High Low current day",overlay=true)
var Current_High = -999999.0
var Current_Low = 999999.0
var startday=0
[h,l,bi]=request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [high,low,bar_index], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
if bi!=bi[1]
    startday:=bar_index
if barstate.islast
    Current_High:=h
    Current_Low:=l
    linehigh=line.new(startday,Current_High,bar_index,Current_High)
    linelow=line.new(startday,Current_Low,bar_index,Current_Low)
    line.delete(id=linehigh[1])
    line.delete(id=linelow[1])
```

[image: Working Image]